# how soon on page load can I read the pathname?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router

I've got a page showing a list of records:
**myapp.com/records/**
and a page showing the details of a selected record:
**myapp.com/record-details/497**

(I'm using ui-router and angular so my path is specified like   **url: '/record-details/:id/'**)

QA has discovered that, from one record page, they can hack the URL to try to hit another record like this: **myapp.com/record-details/498**

I want to prevent this.

The data for the correct record are passed internally, via JavaScript, from list to details page, so I have a chance to compare. So what I'm doing is comparing the  recordId passed via JS with the id extracted from the URL. If they do not match then someone is trying to hack the URL and I can reroute the page.

Unfortunately, the URL is NOT AVAILABLE when I first test it. I wish to understand why not, and how long it will take to be available.

The code in my **record-details** page starts like this:

```
function init(){
   // do some regex manipulation of pathname
   // compare url-RecordId with in-memory-RecordId
   console.log('rawurl : ' + window.location.pathname);
}
init();
```

Output:

**rawurl : myapp.com/records/**

So: when loading my DETAILS page, the pathname variable is still pointing at the record list page!

The longer I wait for pathname to reflect the details page URL, the longer my page is visible to the user as blank, broken and about to be rerouted, which is a terrible user experience.

How can I quickly and efficiently reroute the page?

Comment: Don't try to detect people interfering with the URL. Just use authentication and authorization to make sure that the user making the request is allowed to access that content.

Comment: And no : angular.element(document).ready does NOT fix the problem...

Comment: instantly: if you can run the JS, you can use the URL

Comment: @Quention: how? More to the point: that would be changing the requirements - i.e. this behavior should be allowed (within authorization rights).

Comment: @dandavis: False. Thought I made that clear. See output.

Comment: i meant that window.location.pathname will always be right. it's built-in, so it cannot be wrong or "slow". only simulated routing could cause such delay, but i don't see that happening if the user types into the URL bar: it should just navigate to the page in the url...

Comment: This code on the details page: console.log('rawurl : ' + window.location.pathname)
returns the URL of the summary page for the first few moments. Eventually it is correct.

Comment: @DaveC426913: the path is wrong for the first few moments after typing a new resource id the url bar and thus reloading the page?  (or did i misunderstand what you meant by "hack the URL"?) aside: if location.pathname doesn't work for you, use a different value that you can trust. pathname IS available way before onload, but it sounds like pathname is not the droids you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you should never try to circumvent server actions (so the get request for /records/{id} with client side code.  The malicious user can replace your javascript file with their own, or even just skip over your verification code.

As Quentin mentioned in a comment, a better and more secure solution would to use the Authorise/Authentication layer on your server side code to ensure the user is allowed to request that record.  Although I don't know how your membership schema works so I can't comment on the specifics.  Hopes this points you in the right direction!

Comment: but the main point of angular is to circumvent the normal sync reload-to-do-anything client/server model...

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. We're missing a security layer here.

Comment: @dandavis The main point of Angular is to give you a responsive MVVM framework that allows for painless creation of SPA's.  You should still have your server model but you invoke actions via AJAX rather than will full postbacks.  Authorisation can be done on the client side but should always be supported by a server implementation also.

Answer (score 0):

I found the short answer (but it does not address the larger security issues, and doesn't completely solve my problem).

Add the '$location' dependency, then do this:
$location.path()

So, this:

```
console.log(":) " + $location.path());
console.log(":( " + window.location.pathname);
```

outputs this:

```
:) myapp.com/record/497/
:( myapp.com/records/
```

For some reason, it provides the correct URL, even though the angular documentation actually says it is "...based on window.location...".

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Thanks everyone. I will take up the larger security issue with my team.